# ", or } expected while parsing object/hash" error while parsing a JSON file

Tags: json, perl

I'm trying to print the contents of the "name" field of a large .json file and I'm having problems with the parsing. So far I've tried open the .json file using "<:encoding(UTF-8)", but no luck so far.

This is my code, the error is on line 11:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use JSON;

open(my $fh, "<:encoding(UTF-8)", "pokedex.json");
my $ejson = <$fh>;
close($fh);

my $djson = decode_json $ejson;
for(my $i=1;$i<=718;$i++){
    print $djson->{"$i"}{"name"}, "\n";
}
```

The error itself is `, or } expected while parsing object/hash, at character offset 1 (before "\n") at jsonreverser.pl line 11.`

I've ran the .json file through an online verifier, and it said it's correctly formatted. This is the link to the json file: http://vps.zazez.com/junk/pokedex.json

Comment: Try printing $ejson before decoding it, to see if it contains what you think it does. Then look up File::Slurp :-)

Comment: I.. oh. Well, I understand now why it's not working, but why is there a random ; after the { at the beginning? Will this be fixed if I slurp it?

Comment: Where do you see this "random ';'"?

Comment: Once again, another dumb mistake. The ';' was from the Data::Dumper. I understood now, and it works with File::Slurp. Thanks.

Comment: Glad you found the solution(s) yourself!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
my $ejson = <$fh>;
```

is an assignment in scalar context, so you are only loading the first line of the input file into `$ejson`.

There are many ways to load an entire input stream into a scalar:

```
my $ejson = join '', <$fh>;

my $ejson = do {
    local $/;
    <$fh>;
};
```

Or use `File::Slurp` as asjo suggests.

Comment: Oh god, this is a silly mistake. Last time I parsed a JSON was when I used the reddit API, and that returned a full JSON file into a single variable. I completely forgot about the context. Thanks for the clarification.