# decoding JSON issue in Perl code: , or ] expected while parsing array, at character offset

Tags: json, perl

I have written Perl code that was working until recently, when I tried to run it again. The problem seems to originate from the JSON::XS "decode_json" method.

Code Snippet:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use MooseX::Singleton;
use Array::Utils qw(:all);
use Data::Dumper;
use JSON::XS qw(encode_json decode_json);
use Storable;
use Tie::IxHash;

    open (my $observations_fh, '<', 'observations.json') or die "Could not open observations.json\n";
    my $observations_json = <$obserations_fh>;
    my @decoded_observations = @{decode_json($observations_json)};
```

Usually, after this code I was able to go through each JSON component in a for loop and take specific information, but now I get the error:

> , or ] expected while parsing array, at character offset 5144816
>   (before "(end of string)")

I saw a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24959739/or-expected-while-parsing-object-hash-error-while-parsing-a-json-file), but it didn't resolve my problem.

I also have similar json decoding going on that doesn't utilize @{decode_json($variable)}, but when I tried that with this observations.json file, the same error was output.

I also tried just using the JSON module, but same error occurred.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

-cookersjs

Comment: If you have not modified `$/` this `my $observations_json = <$obserations_fh>` will only read one line from the file. Maybe you did not read everything, and it became malformed?

Comment: Hakon's right.  I suggest using File::Slurp; i.e. my $observations_json = read_file('observations.json');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That probably indicates you have incomplete JSON in `$observations_json`. Your assumption that the entire file consists of just one line is probably incorrect. Use

```
my $observations;
{
    open (my $observations_fh, '<', 'observations.json')
        or die("Can't open observations.json: $!\n");

    local $/;
    my $observations_json = <$obserations_fh>;
    $observations = decode_json($observations_json);
}
```

If that doesn't help, `observations.json` doesn't contain valid JSON.

Comment: Yea, it turns out the JSON file was not downloaded fully, which is odd. I downloaded it using HTTP::Request so I am not really sure why that happened, but oh well now I at least know the source of the problem. Its a 106 MB JSON file, and I have two other JSON files that downloaded fully that are smaller, so the size of the file must have caused some kind of issue